# why transition-group not working?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

[jsffidle](https://jsfiddle.net/cjd07nus/13/)

```
  <div class="container">
   <input placeholder="find PLEASE" v-model="search" />
   <transition-group name="fade">
    <div v-for="(item, index) in filteredItems" :key="index" class="container__item">{{ item }}</div>
```

```
.container {
 display: flex;
 flex-wrap: wrap;
 flex-direction: column;

}
new Vue({
el: '.container',
 data() {
return {
  search: '',
   items: ['lorem opas', 'opas loram ', 'mushroms so good']
   }
},
computed: {
 filteredItems() {
  return this.items.filter(item => item.indexOf(this.search) > -1)
}
}
})
```

Why transition-group animation not worked? all items have a unique key, also  I get the name for transition-group.

Comment: What kind of transition are you expecting without any CSS classes to define the transition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your transition is in fact working, however you haven't specified any style for it.

From the [official documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/transitions.html):

> When an element wrapped in a transition component is inserted or
> removed, this is what happens:
>
> Vue will automatically sniff whether the target element has CSS
> transitions or animations applied. If it does, CSS transition classes
> will be added/removed at appropriate timings.

To make your example work, you can have like so:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '.container',
  data() {
    return {
      search: '',
      items: [
        'lorem opas', 
        'opas loram ', 
        'mushroms so good'
      ]
    }
  },
  computed: {
    filteredItems() {
      return this.items.filter(item => 
        item.indexOf(this.search) > -1
      )
    }
  }
})
```

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.fade-enter-active, .fade-leave-active {
  transition: opacity .5s;
}
.fade-enter, .fade-leave-to {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <input placeholder="find PLEASE" v-model="search" />
  <transition-group name="fade">
    <div class="container__item" 
      v-for="(item, index) in filteredItems" 
      :key="index"
    >
      {{ item }}
    </div>
  </transition-group>
</div>
```

All that was missing were the CSS transition classes.

```
<transition-group name="fade">
```

In this case, the specified name should be the prefix of all the css classes. Currently there are [6 transition classes](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/transitions.html#Transition-Classes) that vue uses, which for the example above, would be the following:

1. fade-enter
2. fade-enter-active
3. fade-enter-to
4. fade-leave
5. fade-leave-active
6. fade-leave-to

Also note that you can share the same classes with multiple instances of this `transition-group` in your app.